# How to include Windows.Security.Credentials.UI namespace into C# project

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-runtime

My goal is to work with [`Windows.Security.Credentials.UI`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.credentials.ui.userconsentverifier) namespace to create a program that authenticates users through their Windows pin, similar to `Opera Password Manager`:

[image: opera_password_manager_image]

The only problem is that I cannot figure out how to include the namespace into my program.

I've tried including it as so:

```
using Windows.Security.Credentials.UI;
```

However, that returned an error:

```
The type or namespace name 'Windows' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I have also tried to include the namespace as a reference but I cannot locate it inside the References menu.

**What is the correct method to install the [`Windows.Security.Credentials.UI`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.credentials.ui.userconsentverifier) namespace in `C# .NET 4.7.2` Console Application?**

Answer (score 1):

When using the .NET Framework, you must include the [Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts) and then you will have access to (some) WinRT APIs.

Here is a sample C# Console Application:

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main()
    {
        await Windows.Security.Credentials.UI.UserConsentVerifier.RequestVerificationAsync("hello world").AsTask();
    }
}
```

It works because this API is marked as [DualApiPartition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/apiindex/uwp-apis-callable-from-a-classic-desktop-app#the-dualapipartition-attribute).

Also make sure you're using PackagesReference format for nuget packages and *not* the [packages.config configuration](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference/).

Comment: I've tried this and got a similar error: `The type or namespace name 'Security' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows' `

Comment: Have you included the nuget package?

Comment: Yes, that's the error after including the package.

Comment: I doubt it. Please post your reproducing project somewhere.

Comment: It's a console application, do you think that's the problem?

Comment: No I've tested it like that. Post a reproducing project somewhere.

Comment: I've uploaded the source code to: https://ufile.io/b1mi44nn

Comment: I think it's because you use the "old" packages.config way of using nuget. Migrate to PackageReferences. This is the final .csproj I modified and now it works https://pastebin.com/raw/5TMQ3xdP

Comment: You also need to include reference to winmd file of Win SDK in case of .NET Framework. In case of .NET Core you can specify SDK version inside projects's TargetFramework property.